# how to append something to array correctly?

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview, cell

I'm going to make a custom cell, already have some labels on it, then I create a cell object and array, try to append that object to array then show on table, but after append, there's no content in my array's properties

I've tried to find out solutions but likely no one has these problems

//tableview implement

```swift
var recordCell : [RecordCell] = []
let note = RecordCell()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.recordCell.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recordCell",for: indexPath) as! RecordCell
        let indexPath = indexPath.row


        cell.recordFileName?.text = self.recordCell[indexPath].recordFileName?.text
        cell.recordDate?.text = self.recordCell[indexPath].recordDate?.text
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.playBtn.tag = indexPath
        return cell
    }
```

//append to array

```swift
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "請輸入錄音名稱", message: "錄音名稱", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (_) in
            var name : String = ""
            if(alertController.textFields![0].text == ""){
                name = "record"
            }else{
                name = alertController.textFields![0].text!
            }

            guard self.audioRecorder == nil else{return}
                self.recordNumber += 1
                self.record.isEnabled = false
                self.pause.isEnabled = true
                self.stop.isEnabled = true
                let destinationUrl = self.getFileURL().appendingPathComponent("\(name).m4a")

                let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                                AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
                ]

                do {
                    self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: destinationUrl, settings: settings)
                    self.audioRecorder.record()
                    self.note.recordFileName?.text = name
                    self.note.recordDate?.text = self.getDate()
                    self.recordCell.append(self.note)
                } catch {
                    print("Record error:", error.localizedDescription)
                }

        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "取消", style: .cancel) { (_) in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.audioRecorder.stop()
            })
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "輸入名稱"
            textField.keyboardType = .default
        }
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alertController,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
```

I expect when I append something, there's something in array

Comment: Is it that the array isn't being appended to (should be able to tell from debugging), or is it that you're not calling `tableView.reloadData()` to redraw the table?

Answer (score 0):

After appending a new value to the array, call [`insertRows`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows) method like this

```
self.recordCell.append(self.note)
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: recordCell.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt see anything wrong.

Are you sure your code is called? Try giving a print() right before adding and see if it's called.

Maybe it's not called because of `guard self.audioRecorder == nil else{return}`